# Comparing bitmap is not working

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to compare the bitmap 1 to bitmap 2 and if they equal to 0 I want them to do something. so for sake of seeing what it's returning I added a trace. but it seems like it's tracing out something totally different from what I expected. This is the code:

```
var scratch_c : Scratch_card = new Scratch_card ();
var backgr: Background = new Background ();
var mouseclick:Number;
var masking:Sprite = new Sprite()

var bmd1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(742, 165);
var bm:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd1);
addChild (bm);
bm.x=20;
bm.y=40;
bmd1.draw(scratch_c);

var bmd2:BitmapData = new BitmapData(742, 165);
var bm2:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd2);
addChild (bm2);
bm2.x=20;
bm2.y=40;
bmd2.draw(backgr);
bm2.mask = masking;
addChild(masking);


stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, Pressing);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, Moving);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, Lifting);


function Pressing(event:MouseEvent):void {
mouseclick = 1;
}


function Moving(event:MouseEvent):void {
if (mouseclick == 1) {
masking.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
masking.graphics.drawEllipse(mouseX, mouseY, 70, 60);
masking.graphics.endFill();

}
}


function Lifting(event:MouseEvent):void {
trace(bmd1.compare(bmd2));
mouseclick = 0;
}
```

This is what it is tracing out[image: Trace:]

How can I make it compare the pixels of bmd1 and bmd2?
Why is it not returning a number?

Answer (score 3):

> Not a percentage but it should return a new BitMapData object that you could assign as an image.
>   BitMapData.compare( )

Returns Object — If the two BitmapData objects have the same dimensions (width and height), the method returns a new BitmapData object that has the difference between the two objects (see the main discussion). If the BitmapData objects are equivalent, the method returns the number 0. If the widths of the BitmapData objects are not equal, the method returns the number -3. If the heights of the BitmapData objects are not equal, the method returns the number -4.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136048/comparing-two-bitmapdata-in-actionscript-3)

Result:

> Your bitmaps are not equivalent, thats why you get an object made of 2 different bitmaps.

Comment: how can I assign it as an image for something else? I am kind of confused on the part that it is masked and hasn't been relieved completely why is it still returning that?

Comment: On the first you do `bmd1.draw(scratch_c);` on the second `bmd2.draw(backgr);`. In my opinion this is the reason of your BitmapData difference. Hope I helped you.

Comment: hummm just for sake of testing purposes I added a copy of the same picture again without adding it on the stage. well it does return 0.. now my question turns into ...how can I compare them only after knowing that the whole image has been unmasked or reviled.. I only want to compare the part of the image that is masked with the overall and if that returns 0 I want it to do soemthing

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
if(bmd1.compare(bmd2) == bmd2){
    // complete
}
```

However after looking at your code a little more. i think you need to test on the masking not bmd1
So something like this.

```
var mymask:BitmapData = new BitmapData(742, 165, true,0x000000000);
mymask.draw(masking);

if(mymask.compare(bmd2) == bmd2){
    // complete
}
```

untested code but should put you on the right path

Comment: thank you i did oce up with an answer but it was very far from what I asked..I didn't really sue bitmaps all together I just used better code for testing masking